need help getting an SSL cert for AWS GameLift
I'm new to AWS and currently working on integrating Amazon GameLift with my game, which uses Unity and Mirror for WebGL. I have a few questions regarding SSL certificates:
Do I need to obtain an SSL certificate each time a new fleet is created in GameLift?

How do I obtain an SSL certificate for use with GameLift?

I'm calling my functions in aws lambda script.
`import json
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
client = boto3.client('gamelift')
# Oyun oturumu arama
search_response = client.search_game_sessions(
    FleetId='my-fleet-id',
    FilterExpression="hasAvailablePlayerSessions=true"
)

if search_response['GameSessions']:
    game_session = search_response['GameSessions'][0]

    response = {
        'ipAddress': game_session['IpAddress'],
        'port': game_session['Port'],
        'gameSessionId': game_session['GameSessionId']
    }
else:
    create_response = client.create_game_session(
        FleetId='my-fleet-id',
        MaximumPlayerSessionCount=2
    )
    game_session = create_response['GameSession']

    
    response = {
        'ipAddress': game_session['IpAddress'],
        'port': game_session['Port'],
        'gameSessionId': game_session['GameSessionId']
    }

return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps(response)
}`

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
